# Custom layout for Google Cast 'ExpandedControlsActivity'

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-custom-view, google-cast

Is it possible to have a custom layout for 'ExpandedControlsActivity' in an android application? I want to add a button to the standard layout which will allow the user to choose from different video streams (low/high).

At the moment i am using the standard one;

[Google codelabs - Cast SDK v3 Android Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#9)

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not have control over the layout. You can only use one of the pre-defined actions for the buttons on that screen. You can, however, write your own custom activity and have that act as the Expanded Controller (i.e. be invoked if user, say, taps on the mini controller). Given that it is easy to use UiMediaController to bind ui components of your app to the remote session, writing such activity shouldn't be too much trouble.

Comment: i want to allow user to choose high/low streams of the same video while the video is playing, how can i do that? can i achieve it with the standard layout or do i have to implement my own?

Comment: As I said earlier, you do not have control over the layout unless you create your own version of it.

Comment: in iOS, is it possible to use a custom UIViewController to act as ExpandedController ?

Answer (score 0):

For addition of any custom layout you need to modify activity_layout.xml and activity.java in order to add the feature.

But you dont have Access to the ExpandedControlsActivity layout file as it is extended from ExpandedControllerActivity.

So only way is to write your own activity and than use that instead of ExpandedControlsActivity.